# Trato de renderizar con Angular un objeto de arrays traído de un API pero en vez de la Información me renderiza el tipo de dato Object

Tags: javascript, angular, api, data

espero estén muy bien, estoy intentado renderizar los datos de una API con Angular, pero al hacerlo me imprime el tipo Object en vez de la información, se que estoy fallando en algún concepto pero no logro saber como solucionarlo, este es el codigo:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  datos: []= []

  constructor (private http: HttpClient){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDataApi()
  }
  getDataApi(){
    return this.http.get('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.datos= data.values //almaceno los datos
      console.log(this.datos);
    })
  }
}
```

Acá esta el componente html, solo tiene esto que es el array donde guarde la información que traje desde el API:

```
<p > {{ datos }} </p>
```

Ahora esto es lo que me renderiza en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información que me traje de la Api viene en un objeto con arrays de objetos dentro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho si alguien supiera la respuesta sobre en que estoy fallando

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres ver de golpe todo el contenido, tendrás que que añadir

```
<p>{{ datos | json}}</p>
```

Pero si realmente quieres ver cada objetos con sus atributos

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let dato of datos; let i = index"> 
<p>{{dato.nombre}}</p> /* Por ejemplo, no se las propiedades del objeto*/
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva saludos.

Comment: @JuanCalorsQuilesEstruch En realidad quiero renderizar cierta información de la API en el html pero en vez de la Información me aparece el el tipo de dato Object y eso es lo que no entiendo Brother

Comment: Esos datos tendrán una estructura, si puedes poner un ejemplo, por si fueran datos de datos, podría poner un ejemplo más concreto. Con en ngfor sería la solución, me hace falta un poco más de información para darte una solución.

Comment: Por eso es importante crear un tipado de los datos que obtenemos de cualquier api, con la sentencia `<p>{{ datos | json}}</p>` imprimes el resultado completo en tu html, el cual puedes copiar y usar la web `https://app.quicktype.io/` que te generara el tipado, que le aplicas a `datos: []= []` de esta forma `datos: tipado[]= []` con eso puedes saber exactamente que datos trae tu respuesta y trabajar con ella

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta el comentario anterior te muestro, utilice la url de tu API y obtuve la respuesta tal como tú. La pase por la web que te mencione `https://app.quicktype.io/` y obtuve este tipado para tu respuesta.

```
export interface RespuestaAPi {
    values: Value[];
}

export interface Value {
    first_name: string;
    h_in:       string;
    h_meters:   string;
    last_name:  string;
}
```

Con esto cree un archio llamado ej: `tipado.interface.ts`, que uso en el componente. Tu código debería cambiar así

```
import {Value} from '<carpeta donde esta el archivo>/tipado.interfaces.ts'

export class AppComponent  {

  datos: Value[]= []

  constructor (private http: HttpClient){  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDataApi()
  }

  getDataApi(){
    return this.http.get('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.datos= data.values //almaceno los datos
     })
  }
}
```

Luego en tu html puedes mostrar tu información ejemplo una tabla:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Altura in</th>
            <th>Altura m</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
        </tr>

         <tr *ngFor='let dt of datos'>
            <td>{{dt.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{dt.h_in}}</td>
            <td>{{dt.h_meters}}</td>
            <td>{{dt.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

y tienes la muestra de tu respuesta, espero te sirva